# I can't install pip packages and I get traceback error

Tags: python, pip, traceback, python-3.10

```
pip install clipboard
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 287, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 75, in get_default_session  
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 89, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 157, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\__init__.py", line 75, in get_default_environment
    return select_backend().Environment.default()
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\__init__.py", line 63, in select_backend
    from . import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\pkg_resources.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2785, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygoogle\google.py", line 113
    print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: It looks as if you’ve installed an old package `pygoogle` that doesn’t work with Python 3. I would try uninstalling it with `pip uninstall pygoogle`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use pyperclip as it is the same a s clipboard and it is newer.

https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

```
import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
```

Currently only handles plaintext.

On Windows, no additional modules are needed.

On Mac, this module makes use of the pbcopy and pbpaste commands, which should come with the os.

On Linux, this module makes use of the xclip or xsel commands, which should come with the os. Otherwise run “sudo apt-get install xclip” or “sudo apt-get install xsel” (Note: xsel does not always seem to work.)

Otherwise on Linux, you will need the gtk or PyQt4 modules installed.

I hope this help. :)

Comment: pyper clip worked but also if I want to install any other package I get the same problem

Comment: I think you should check this out    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958307/why-cant-i-install-packages-from-pypi-with-pip